# Will a local environment be deleted if there's a name in .GlobalEnv pointing to a data.table created in that local environment?

Tags: r, data.table

Imagine we're having an environment with some local variables in it along with a data.table.

```
local({
    vecl <- 1:10
    lstl <- as.list(1:10)        
    dtl <- data.table(num = 1:3, chr = letters[1:3])

    .GlobalEnv$dtG <- dtl
})
```

It is expected that data that is pointed to by name `dtl` will preserve, due to data.table's by-reference essence.
But what about the data, that `vecl` and `lstl` point to: will it be cleaned out from memory after `local()` finishes? Or it will still sit in memory, because execution environment of `local()` will not be dropped because there's a pointer (`dtG`) to the data created in this environment (like when using closures)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reference to `vec1` or `lst1`, so they'll be collected. One way to verify this is to create an environment with a finalizer. The finalizer is run when the environment is garbage collected. So

```
dtl <- local({
    env <- new.env()
    reg.finalizer(env, function(...) message("cleaning"))
    data.table(num = 1:3, chr <- letters[1:3])
})
```

and then

```
> gc()
cleaning
         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 309015 16.6     592000 31.7   460000 24.6
Vcells 530523  4.1    1023718  7.9   785050  6.0
```

In contrast,

```
fun <- local({
    env <- new.env()
    reg.finalizer(env, function(...) message("cleaning"))
    function() {}
})
```

and

```
> gc()
         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 309038 16.6     592000 31.7   460000 24.6
Vcells 530159  4.1    1023718  7.9   785050  6.0
> rm(fun)
> gc()
cleaning
         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 309152 16.6     592000 31.7   460000 24.6
Vcells 530516  4.1    1023718  7.9   785050  6.0
```

Comment: Thanks, examples are pretty illustrative.